# Draw an audio waveform using QAudioDecode and QPainter

Tags: c++, qt, audio, qwidget, waveform

I'm trying to draw an waveform using QT and so far everything goes fine except some small gaps in the waveform and issues with correctly setting up the zoom level.

Using the code bellow this is the results I get. It looks pretty close but it still has some issues like the waveform exceeds the width of the widget. The zoom level is incorrect, since I also had to zoom the audacity waveform to get a close match. And also there are a few gaps in the waveform I don't know how to fix.

**EDIT:**

Fixed it in the draw function:

```cpp
float xScale = (float)width() / count;
float xScale = (float)width() / count;
        for(int i = 0; i < numberOfSamples; ++i)
            painter.drawRect(i * xScale, center - (samples[i] * center), 2, (samples[i] * center) * 2);
```

Now the issue I'm having is that if I use a sample rate of 44100Hz I can't figure out how to make the waveform draw correctly.

**ORIGINAL TEXT:**

Here's the photo of the waveform with zoomed audacity.

[image]

Here's how audacity looks unzoomed, and my waveform should look like too:

[image]

And here is my code (source code can be find at https://github.com/nitanmarcel/vpsplayer/tree/waveform_new:

waveform.cpp

```cpp
#include "waveform.h"

Waveform::Waveform(QObject *parent)
{
    targetFormat = QAudioFormat(QAudioDeviceInfo::defaultOutputDevice().preferredFormat());
    targetFormat.setCodec(QStringLiteral("audio/pcm"));
    targetFormat.setSampleType(QAudioFormat::SignedInt);
    //targetFormat.setSampleSize(16);
    if (QSysInfo::ByteOrder == QSysInfo::BigEndian)
      targetFormat.setByteOrder(QAudioFormat::BigEndian);
    else
      targetFormat.setByteOrder(QAudioFormat::LittleEndian);
    qDebug() << "Sample rate:" << targetFormat.sampleRate();
    qDebug() << "Channel count:" << targetFormat.channelCount();

    QAudioFormat decodeFormat(targetFormat);
    decodeFormat.setSampleType(QAudioFormat::Float);

    audioDecoder = new QAudioDecoder;
    audioDecoder->setAudioFormat(decodeFormat);
    audioDecoder->setSourceFilename("/home/nitanmarcel/sample2.mp3");
    audioDecoder->start();

    connect(audioDecoder, &QAudioDecoder::bufferReady, this, &Waveform::appendSamples);
    connect(audioDecoder, &QAudioDecoder::finished, [this]() { emit decodeFinished(); });


}

Waveform::~Waveform()
{

}

void Waveform::appendSamples()
{
    buffer = audioDecoder->read();
    qreal peak = getPeakValue(buffer.format());
    const qint16 *data = buffer.constData<qint16>();
    int count = buffer.sampleCount() / 2;
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i += targetFormat.sampleRate() / 40){ // I want 40 samples per second
        double val = data[i]/peak;
        samples.append(val);
    }
}

QVector<double> Waveform::getSamples()
{
    return samples;
}

qreal Waveform::getPeakValue(const QAudioFormat &format)
{
    qreal ret(0);
    if (format.isValid()){
        switch (format.sampleType()) {

            case QAudioFormat::Unknown:
            break;
            case QAudioFormat::Float:
                if (format.sampleSize() != 32)
                    ret = 0;
                else
                    ret = 1.00003;
            break;
            case QAudioFormat::SignedInt:
                if (format.sampleSize() == 32)
                    ret = INT_MAX;
                else if (format.sampleSize() == 16)
                    ret = SHRT_MAX;
                else if (format.sampleSize() == 8)
                    ret = CHAR_MAX;
                break;
            case QAudioFormat::UnSignedInt:
                if (format.sampleSize() == 32)
                    ret = UINT_MAX;
                else if (format.sampleSize() == 16)
                    ret = USHRT_MAX;
                else if (format.sampleSize() == 8)
                    ret = UCHAR_MAX;
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
    }
    return ret;
}
```

waveformwidget.cpp

```cpp
#include "waveformwidget.h"
#include <QDebug>

WaveformWidget::WaveformWidget(QWidget *parent)
{
    clearFocus();
    setFocusPolicy(Qt::NoFocus);

    waveformReady = false;

    m_waveform = new Waveform();
    m_pixLabel = new QLabel(this);
    m_pixLabel->show();
    this->m_paintTimer = new QTimer(this);
    connect(this->m_paintTimer, &QTimer::timeout, this, &WaveformWidget::drawWave);
    m_paintTimer->setInterval(100);
    m_paintTimer->start();
    show();

    connect(m_waveform, &Waveform::decodeFinished, [this]() { waveformReady = true; });
}

WaveformWidget::~WaveformWidget()
{
}

void WaveformWidget::drawWave()
{
    if (!waveformReady)
        return;
    QVector<double> samples = m_waveform->getSamples();
    int numberOfSamples = samples.size();
    //qDebug() << "Samples size " << numberOfSamples;
    m_pixMap = QPixmap(this->size());
    m_pixMap.scaled(size());
    m_pixMap.fill(Qt::black);
    QPainter painter(&m_pixMap);
    painter.setPen(Qt::red);
    for(int i = 0; i < numberOfSamples; ++i){
        //qDebug() << height();
        painter.drawRect(i * 2, height()/2 - (samples[i] * height()), 2, (samples[i] * height()) * 2);
    }

    m_pixLabel->setPixmap(m_pixMap);
    m_pixLabel->resize(size());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**First issue with resizing:**

I just had to correctly take in consideration the width of the canvas:

```cpp
float xScale = (float)width() / count;
float xScale = (float)width() / count;
        for(int i = 0; i < numberOfSamples; ++i)
            painter.drawRect(i * xScale, center - (samples[i] * center), 2, (samples[i] * center) * 2);
```

**Broken waveform drawing on changed sample count and sample rate:**

Found my answer in a spectrum analyzer application on github.

Getting the peak values and was the correct way of doing it. the only changes I did we're to the data cast and type and how I returned the value divided by the resulting peak.

I only work with float sample types so I can delete the peak function and use directly the 1.00003 value for the peak. Original code that also contains all the peak values and calculation for different sample types can be found here https://github.com/danielholanda/Qt-Audio-Spectrum-Analyzer/blob/master/Qt_code/mainwindow.cpp#L229

```cpp
void WaveformWidget::appendSamples(QAudioBuffer buffer)
{
    QAudioBuffer::S32F *data = buffer.data<QAudioBuffer::S32F>();
    qreal peakValue = qreal(1.00003); // sample type is always of type float
    int count = buffer.sampleCount() / 2;
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i += 1050){ // I want 42 samples. Sample rate is always 44100.
        double val = data[i].left/peakValue;
        samples.append(val);
    }
}
```